# AWS cannot open or download after copy files to different Amazon S3 bucket using Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have created a lambda with boto3 that copies files from one Amazon S3 bucket to a different account's Amazon S3 bucket. Everything works fine, but when the other user is trying to open or download the files gets access denied or cannot download the files.
I have the bucket location of the other account and the kms key and i have created policy role for that on my bucket. My bucket has encryption enabled.
Do i need to decrypt my files and encrypt with the kms key of the other account ? I am testing with  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/programming-encryption.html#reencryption  is this correct ?
Thanks

Comment: If you copied to other account, you may still be owner of the objects. Thus the other person can't read the files.

Comment: @Marcin  ok then what do i need todo. Decrypt and encrypt with other person kms key or something else? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an object ownership issue. You will need to grant the destination bucket `bucket-owner-full-control` to the object when uploading. You can set a bucket policy which blocks uploads unless the uploader grants this access:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html

Comment: Yes. This happens when an object is 'pushed' to an Amazon S3 bucket owned by a different account. Setting that ACL will fix the situation. It does _not_ occur when 'pulling' an object from a bucket owned by a different account.